# Angular FormArray valueChanges executing multiple times after change

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form with a FormAwway where it shows the products within a purchase made, this is my component:

```
constructor() {
    this.purchaseForm = new FormGroup({
        id: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        purchase: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        date: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        products: new FormArray([]),
    });
}

public createNewLine(object: any = {}): FormGroup {
    const newLine = new FormGroup({
      index: new FormControl(null),
      id: new FormControl(object.id, Validators.required),
      id_product: new FormControl(object.id_produto, Validators.required),
      quantity: new FormControl(object.quantidade, Validators.required),
      value_unit: new FormControl(object.valor_unitario, Validators.required),
      value_total: new FormControl(object.valor_total, Validators.required),
    });

    const formArray = <FormArray>this.purchaseForm.get('products');
    newLine.get('index').patchValue(formArray.length);
    newLine.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(400)).subscribe(value => this.updateProductValue(value));

    return newLine;
}

private updateProductValue(object): void {
    const quantity = parseFloat(object.quantity);
    const value_total = parseFloat(object.value_total);
    const formArray = this.purchaseForm.controls['products'] as FormArray;
    
    object.value_unit = value_total / quantity;
    formArray.at(object.index).patchValue(object);
}
```

When I change the input with the quantity or total value I need to update the unit value for that specific product. The problem is that when I do this calculation and update the value, it detects as a new value change and execute that function again, which creates a loop.

What am I doing wrong here? Or what do I need to do to prevent this behavior? Apart from this loop, everything else is working as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change your last line like this:

```
formArray.at(object.index).patchValue(object, { emitEvent: false, onlySelf: true });
```

Comment: I was so frustaded over this I forgot the emitEvent... Thanks!!